# Form elements larger on Ipad broswer than desktop browser

Tags: css, forms, ipad, mobile, responsive-design

My form elements are larger on the Ipad and therefor breaks my design. My Ipad is adding its default form styles to my contact form, and so their width is larger than the div I have them contained in which has a width of 60%.

Here is the page with the issue :
http://jussbuss.tv/testing/kpat/contact/

Any Advice?

Thank you in advance,
Best,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a percentage on your `<div class='cpagetemp'>` it's not just an ipad problem, shrink your browser. Use `px` or `em`, not `%`.